# NPN: Not fully sinking to GND

Tags: digital-logic, npn, logic-level

I'm using an NPN to pull a 12v (5mA) signal low from an MCU (logic level). My problem is that when I pull the 12v line low, 7.4v are still present at the 12v side of the line using the circuit below:

[image: Circuit 1]

When I remove R2 and connect the signal directly to the collector pin on the NPN, about 110mV are still left on the line. See below:
[image: Circuit 2]

Why isn't the NPN fully pulling the line low, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: In your 2nd schematic, your output `signal` will always be 12V, and your input `!signal` will only control how hot your poor transistor gets. Are you sure this is what you intended to draw?

Comment: Are you sure the resistor is actually 4.7K?

Comment: reduce R1 and increase R2. or use a logic-level N-chan FET

Comment: @brhans - I'm a hobbyist, so bear with me -- Yes, this is how I've wired it on my breadboard and tested with my multimeter. Perhaps I'm measuring incorrectly.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Actually, you're right -- it's a 5.6k resistor. I don't have a 4.7k to test with, but I tried 270ohms and still found about 1.2v at the `signal`.

Comment: @dandavis - Could you point me towards an equation I can use to calculate the requisite values?

Comment: V=IR, haha. if you want to push a reasonable 10ma from the MCU, then a 330r resistor would feed the base (3.3v/0.01a) well. the "load" side is slightly more complex,  but i would try a 50k resistor. Actually, i would use an irlz44n, but that's me...

Comment: Most likely your transistor driving signal is not what you expect, have you measured that? If it comes from a MCU, is the pin configured as a push-pull output?

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do with this. What do you mean "when I pull the 12V line low"? Are you varying the 12V power rail?

Comment: @Hearth - The 12v line is a digital logic line from an external device (it's a mute signal for a radio). I'm trying to pull that 12v line to ground with an MCU so I can trigger the mute.

Comment: So basically you want either the line labelled "12V" or the line labelled "!signal" to be able to trigger the mute? Just making sure I have it right.

Comment: `!signal` being pulled high (this is the MCU pin) should pull `12v` (`MUTE`) to ground :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the commenters so far seem to think that the line you labeled "12V" is a power supply. However, I take it that you mean that it is a control signal that is pulled up to 12V — presumably through a pullup resistor of 2400 Ω, since you also specify a current of 5 mA.

Your second circuit is correct, and 110 mV is perfectly reasonable for a saturated NPN transistor @ 5 mA. If your equipment really requires a lower voltage drop than that, then you'll have to try either a logic-level MOSFET or a mechanical relay. Are you saying that the radio is failing to mute using the transistor?

Comment: Dave -- Bingo! I should've made it more clear that the 12v line is a digital logic line only passing 5mA (so your presumption is likely correct). I assumed that the equipment required 0v to "respond" to the mute signal, but I will do some testing to see if the 110mV is low enough to trigger the mute. Given the 5mA being passed, I'm safe to use schematic #2 without risking the BJT, right?

Comment: Right. The 2N3904 would safely handle several hundred mA.

Comment: Perfect! I will test the circuit with speakers connected to ensure the output is muted. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The NPN should pull the signal line down when enabled to the 10mV's range. In the second schematic you show an NPN connected directly to the 12V line. This would dissipate approximately 1 watt which is exceeding the absolute maximum rating of the part and probably causing it to fail.

Check the 2n3094 [with a multimeter](https://vetco.net/blog/test-a-transistor-with-a-multimeter/2017-05-04-12-25-37-07), if it's bad replace it (or just replace it with a new one). IF it looks good then check the resistor or the wiring. Do a conductivity test on the circuit [with the meter](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-multimeter/continuity) to make sure it matches the schematic.

Comment: Actually, the NPN tested out good. I tested at `signal` and I'm indeed getting sub-100mV voltage using schematic #1. However, why am I still seeing ~7v on the 12v side of R2? Essentially, I need to pull that 12v signal to GND, so I'm just a little confused :)

Comment: How much current can the 12V signal source?

Comment: 5mA is what it tested at.